# "DoesNotExist: ContentType matching query does not exist" only happens occassionally

Tags: django, django-templates, django-contenttypes

Pretty simple code but a weird situation...

have a template with this snippet:

```
{% is_contest story as iscontest %}
```

where is_contest is this custom template tag:

```
@register.assignment_tag
def is_contest(obj):
    contesttype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Contest)
    return obj.source_content_type == contesttype
```

But Contest is in the django_content_type table.

Weirdest part: This is only an intermittent error, and only seems to be caused by the template tag (I do this check in views too but no errors there).

Any ideas?

EDIT: Full Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

  File "/home/ubuntu/src/cbframe/commentableobjects/views/commentableobject_list.py", line 142, in commentablobject_list
    return render_to_response('commentableobjects-list.html', info, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 20, in render_to_response
    return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 176, in render_to_string
    return t.render(context_instance)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 123, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 281, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 155, in render
    return self.render_template(self.template, context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 137, in render_template
    output = template.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 185, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render(context))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 1139, in render
    context[self.target_var] = func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

  File "/home/ubuntu/src/cbframe/commentableobjects/templatetags/url_target_blank.py", line 27, in is_contest
    return obj.source_content_type == contesttype

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 350, in __get__
    rel_obj = qs.get(**params)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 366, in get
    % self.model._meta.object_name)

DoesNotExist: ContentType matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem might be that you are comparing 2 instances with eachother, while these should be the same in Django since Django caches them, that is not a guarantee.

Not sure how/where the `source_content_type` comes from, but I would recommend this instead:

```
return isinstance(obj, contesttype)
```

As for the original problem, do you have a stacktrace? This error seems a bit strange.

Are you sure that `Contest` isn't being overwritten somewhere in the scope?
`Contest` could be overwritten by other code in the module, the most likely suspect in that case would be a `global Contest` but that doesn't appear to be the case here.

[edit]

Thanks to the stacktrace the problem is a bit clearer.

This part specifically shows that it's going wrong in the `obj.source_content_type` part:

```
return obj.source_content_type == contesttype
```

I think that some object doesn't have an existing `source_content_type` anymore.

Comment: source_content_type is a field of obj (i.e.... the content type... of the object's source... see?). So I'm not comparing the two objects, I'm comparing a field of one against the other. How would Contest be overwritten? It's a simple model import.

Comment: Thanks for the stacktrace @Colleen, now I know what the problem is :)
It's not actually the `Contest` object that can't be found, but the `source_content_type`. It's using a type that apparently doesn't exist (anymore).

Comment: I was assuming that the query wasn't getting evaluated until the next line, as it is common in Django for queries to delay evaluation until necessary. The default was set to 0 for source_content_type, an object was created wrong and got the default value, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @Colleen: these things can be tricky indeed, one way to ease debugging is printing the value of `contesttype` and `obj.source_content_type` before, it will be trivial to see which of the two is causing the error in that case :)